# Не присваивается класс "show" в JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Всем привет! Вопрос: настроил в JS присваивание классов "show" и "no-scroll" в HTML. Только вот "no-scroll" работает, а "show" - нет. Не могу разобраться почему.

```
<div class="modal" id="becomeClientModal">
        <div class="modal__inner">
            <div class="modal__content">
                <div class="modal__header">
                    <h4 class="modal__title">Need to deliver your cargo?
        We can help!</h4>
                    <div class="modal__text">
                        <p>Fill a little form and we will call you back!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <form class="form" action="/" method="post">
                    <div class="form__group">
                        <input class="input  input--dark  input--user" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__group">
                        <input class="input  input--dark  input--phone" type="tel" placeholder="Your phone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__group">
                        <input class="input  input--dark  input--email" type="email" placeholder="Your email">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn  btn--block  btn--orange" type="submit">
                        <span>Call me back</span>
                    </button>
                </form>

                <div class="modal__footer">
                    <h4 class="modal__footer-title">Our contacts</h4>
                    <address class="modal__contacts">
                        <p>New York, Street, ZIP code</p>
                        <p>Phone: <a href="tel:+9948373123">+9948373123</a></p>
                        <p>E-mail: <a href="mailto:hello@centerlogistic.com">hello@centerlogistic.com</a></p>
                    </address>
                </div>

                <button class="modal__close" type="button" data-modal-close>
                    <img src="assets/images/close.svg" alt="Close">
                </button>
            </div><!-- /.modal__content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal__inner -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->




body {
    margin: 0;
    
    background-color: #fff;
    
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #585858;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}




.modal {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.modal.show {
    display: block;
}




    $('[data-modal]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        let modal = $(this).data('modal');
                
        $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
        $(modal).addClass('show');
    });
    
    $('[data-modal-close]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        let modal =$(this).parents('.modal');
        
        $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
        modal.removeClass('show');
    });
    
});
```

[image: образец]

Comment: А причем тут node.js? Было бы лучше пометить jquery

Comment: "modal.addClass('show');" - не работает так. Пишет, что не "modal.addClass is not a function"

Comment: `$('.modal').addClass('show');`?

Comment: Образец приложил. Там все работает, у меня - нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно класс не присваивается потому что в переменную modal записан не сам элемент, а его data-атрибуты.

```
        let modal = $(this);   
        $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
        $(modal).addClass('show');
```

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: все равно не присваивается...

Comment: Ну или можно просто использовать как селектор класс.  $('.modal').addClass('show');

Comment: ещё бы я добавил бы в css display: block!important; в .modal.show на всякий случай.

Comment: "$('.modal')" - нельзя так т.к. мы объявили его в переменной выше

Comment: Почему вы думаете что нельзя? Если вам обязательно нужна переменная modal, то можно прямо в неё присвоить весь div. можно сделать это в $('document').ready(), что бы div был записан в переменную по готовности документа. 
let modal = $('.modal');  И тогда у вас будет работать и  addClass и removeClass

Comment: Не работает так. Пишет: " не ожидаемый символ "." "

Comment: а можете показать код?